# NextJS GetStaticProps fetch with temporary error - what should we return?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a page with getStaticProps such as:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/getSomeData`)
    const data = await res.json()

    if (!data) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      }
    }

    return {
      props: { data , revalidate: 10}
    }
  } catch (error){
     // if something goes wrong with the fetch request (e.g. ECONNRESET due to timeout) we reach this code
     // what should we return?
  }
}
```

Everything loads ok at build time and the site works. Unfortunately, when a page revalidates and makes a call to example.com there is a timeout (server is down or whatever) and an error is caught.

My question is what should we return in that case. If we return notFound: true then the page never gets revalidated again (once the server is back working).

Comment: You can still return `revalidate: 10` even when returning `notFound: true`, i.e. `return { notFound: true, revalidate: 10 }`.

Comment: notFound will return 404 which is not the correct response. 500 is.